# MapReduce using Python Code; Line not splitting?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am making a MapReduce in Hadoop using python code with two separate files. One is the mapper.py and the other is a reducer.py. My mapper is running fine and gives me the correct output but when I take the output file and put it into the reducer I get this error:

[image]

Here is my reducer code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import sys
output = ""
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    item = line.split('/t', 1)
    print(line)
    print(item)
    person,connections = item
    output = person+":"
    if len(connections.split(":")[0]) > 0:
        output += "Might("
        output += connections.split(":")[0]
        output += ")"
    if len(connections.split(":")[1]) > 0:
        output += " Probably("
        output += connections.split(":")[1]
        output += ")"
    print(output)
```

The thing I think is happening is the line.split('/t', 1) is not splitting for some reason. I would appreciate any kind of help on this!

Here is the output from the mapper:

```
6    3,4,7,1,11:                                                                                                            
1    4,7,6:11                                                                                                               
4    3,6,1,11,12:                                                                                                           
2    10,5,8:9                                                                                                               
12   3,4:                                                                                                                   
3    12,6,4,7,5,8:                                                                                                          
10   5,8,9,2:                                                                                                               
5    2,8,3,10:9                                                                                                             
13   :                                                                                                                      
8    3,5,9,10,2:                                                                                                            
7    1,3,6:                                                                                                                 
11   4,6:1                                                                                                                  
9    8,10:5,2
```

Comment: Typo.  In the split, you have `"/t"` where you wanted `"\t"`.

Comment: Thanks I changed it, and thought that was the issue but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Well, at least one line does not have a tab character.  Is it possible your column is aligned with spaces instead?  Try using `split()` with no parameter.  That will split on all whitespace.

Comment: You might want to look at using `mrjob` library (or pyspark) instead of just reading `sys.stdin`